# Can you add only new data to a view without recreating the entire view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect, but the data within a view is always "up to date" if you query the view because in querying the view, the query used to create the view is also refreshed.  The particular view that I'm creating contains millions of records and I am thus wondering if you can keep the "historical" data in the view and only add new stuff to it?

I do not have table-writing privileges on the database.

EDIT: Real-time tracking data is constantly added to the database, and the view is meant to stitch together a lot of disparate information for easier BI analysis.  So, the "new data" I am referring to is the constant addition of real-time tracking data.

EDIT: I'm writing this from an efficiency perspective (i.e. because there're millions of records, it would take a long time to recreate the entire view in each query).  Maybe what I'm really asking is whether or not SQL Server 2008 would "optimize" this query by only adding the new stuff, would it reload **all** the data, or is there even a way to "optimize" this in such a way as the first case?

Comment: You need to explain in a little more details what you mean my adding data to the view? Do you have some sort of filter on your view?

Comment: When the tracking data gets added to the table that is queried by the view, it will automatically be added to the view.  You don't have to do anything more.   I would suggest googling articles about how views work, because it looks like you have some basic misconceptions about them.

Answer (score 2):

A view is basically a select statement with a name. When you query the view, the query "under the hood" is executed and this is how data fetched is always "fresh".

A solution for your scenario would be to create a different view (or recreate the existent one) where you filter the historical data (exclude rows that are historical, from your point of view by adding an extra condition on a date column). Of course, the other logic should be kept(tables joined, columns, calculations etc etc).

You can also use the existent view and make a new one starting from that. The "body" of the new view should be something like:

```
select *
from (
    select * from existentView -- this should contain an AddedDate (or some sort of date)
) e
where e.AddedDate >= getdate()-30
```